# How can I create a no-frills view config file for HiGlass?

Tags: genomics, visualization

Is there a basic example anywhere that explains how to create a no-frills view
config to view the contact map for a non-human genome assembly using the
server-based viewer at http://higlass.io?

I believe I have a valid .mcool file for the contact map. But looking at the
description of view config files it seems clear those are not created by hand.
I haven't been able to find any place that describes how to create one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I agree that it would seem nice to have one of these in an easily findable place. There is a minimal [JSON](https://github.com/higlass/higlass-manage/blob/master/data/default_options.json) in a repo that might be related but it's not at all clear that it's the same thing. But have you looked at the [tutorial](https://docs.higlass.io/tutorial.html) which seems to have information about getting a quick start on some data? Presumably you have also looked at the [viewconf docs](https://pkerpedjiev.github.io/higlass-docs-beta/view_config.html).